# Can identity NNs do edge detection for grayscale images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

Not CNNs, regular NNs. Also, I'm actually interested in making an AI based edge detector. I've read some papers, but none seem to kick start me. Can anyone share some getting started tips for making edge detectors with AI? CNNs work as classifiers, not image filters. So how can I?

Answer (score 1):

Neural Network's back propagation technique is one of the popular techniques that mainly used for classification process. In the process of back propagation, a convolution matrix will be generated, a knowledge that actually generates the edge from gray level image.

But, I have another doubt what kind of learning you are opting for to train your NN, Supervised or Unsupervised?

Supervised- Train the network with a given set of data sets which can be an edge

Unsupervised- Create input layer with 5 inputs and subtract central pixel from all the neighbour four pixels and thresholding can be  done at output layer.

You can even go for HYBRID APPROACH OF NEURO-FUZZY:-
One the given input image Sobel and Laplacian is applied.
Fuzzy rules are applied on the output we gain from these operators.
In neural network, input layer consists of gradient direction and hidden layer consists of fuzzy data. Both are used to train the network.

Hope, it helps